# ASFD - Will a country be banned forever if fraud is detected on some phone numbers?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

This is a question regarding the [Automatic SMS Fraud Detection (ASFD)](https://www.twilio.com/blog/verify-otp-fraud-detection) feature used in conjunction with the Verify service in Twilio.

The [documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/verify/preventing-toll-fraud/verify-sms-fraud-detection#what-is-verify-automatic-sms-fraud-detection-asfd) reports:

> When there are unusual fluctuations in SMS traffic patterns in a specific location, this feature will automatically **block the prefix of the destination** of the suspected fraud.

#### Question 1

This means that if `+265 87653933` is detected as fraud, then Twilio will block `+265` effectively **disabling the whole country**. Is this understanding correct?

#### Question 2

Considering question 1 answered affirmatively.
Let us say that `+265` got blocked at a certain time. There will ever be a chance for country `+265` to be re-enabled at a certain point, or will it never be enabled again at all?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

### To question 1

Please note that the phone prefix is **not** the same as a country code. It basically is smaller "unit" than the area code. As explained [here](https://linkedphone.com/blog/what-are-the-different-parts-of-a-phone-number-called/#:%7E:text=A%20telephone%20prefix%2C%20also%20called,a%2010%2Ddigit%20phone%20number.):

> A telephone prefix, also called an exchange code or central office code, is a three-digit code that identifies a much smaller region within an area code. The prefix can refer to a specific city or a section of a city. The telephone prefix is the second 3 digits in a 10-digit phone number.

### To question 2

I assume there is no definite answer to this question. I recommend reaching out to support and explain your situation.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using twilo for 3 years now.
According to their terms and conditions.
when your API has been reported for fraud they will give you a 7 week notification as a warning.
if they still get reports that your API is still sending spams.
You will have your API deactivated and account closed.
It does not affect the country code.
it only your API that is affected.

Comment: Hi Denis. I am afraid your answer is not on the subject :( Maybe it is my bad for not being specific enough. I am talking about the SMS Fraud prevention mechanism in Beta.

Comment: My question is about when I use the Verify API and I have activated the ASFD feature.